# If $T^9=T^8$, prove that $T^2=T$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a complex inner product space and $T $ is a normal operator on $V$ such that $T^9=T^8$. Prove that $T^2=T$. Give an example of a non-normal $T$ such that $T^9=T^8$ but $T^2 \ne T$.

Comment: Just to explain why question probably got closed. Sometimes if a question looks like homework moderators want people to show what they have tried to solve the problem because otherwise we would get swarmed by people wanting homework help without having to show any effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: normal operators are diagonalizable.

Comment: Normal operators mean $TT^*=T^*T$ and diagonalisable means $T=SDS^-1$. How can I use this? Sorry I am new to this subject.

Comment: Try to write $T^9=T^8$ in terms of $S$ and $D$. For the example where $T^2 \ne T$, consider nilpotent matrices.

Comment: @nicomezi So, $T^9=SD^9S^{-1}$ and $T^8=SD^8S^{-1}$. If I premultiply by $S^{-1}$ and post multiply by $S$, then $D^9=D^8 \implies D=I \implies D=D^2 \implies T=T^2$. This is ok?

Comment: $D^9=D^8$ does not necessarily imply $D=I$, consider $D=diag(1,0)$ for example.

Comment: If $T^2=T$, then $T$ is a *projection* which has all eigenvalues either $0$ or $1$. Eigenvalues are the numbers showing up in diagonal of $D$ (if you can write it as $TDT^{-1}$ with $D$ diagonal matrix.)

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $x^9 - x^8 = x^8(x-1)$ annihilates $T$ so the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $T$ divides $x^8(x-1)$.

On the other hand, $T$ is normal and hence diagonalizable so $m_T$ consists only of linear factors. Therefore $$m_T \in \{x, x-1, x(x-1)\}$$

and therefore $0 = T(T-I) = T^2 - T$.

---

As an example of a non-normal operator $T$ such that $T^9 = T^8$ but $T^2 \ne T$, we can take

$$T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

with $m_T(x) = x^2(x-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As example for non-normal one just consider any matrix with at least one nilpotent Jordan-block of size 3 or larger. What will happen if we raise those block to 1 or 2 or 3 respectively?

Example of such block:
$$\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: pure awesomeness

Comment: @Chintu you sure it's not dirty awesomeness?